# Logitec StreamCam not listed as a connected device

Tags: drivers, usb, camera

I thought the computer should recognize the Logitec StreamCam after I connect the cam via the USB-C port.However, the device is not listed as one of the connected devices. I verified that the StreamCam I purchased works fine on my Windows laptop.

Below is the output after I ran the `lsusb` command.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c092 Logitech, Inc. G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c33b Logitech, Inc. K840 Mechanical Corded Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: https://davejansen.com/logitech-streamcam-on-linux/

Comment: Also make sure your PC has the hardware requirements, namely *7th Gen Intel®Core™ i5 or later*.

Comment: I have Intel® Core™ i7-7567U CPU on my NUC. Also, I followed the instruction on the link above but it does not work for me somehow. When I ran the command "v4l2-ctl --list-devices", it shows this message: Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.